# Divide SQL data in different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, split, primary-key

I want to split users' data in different tables so that there isn't an huge one containing all data...

The problem is that in tables different from the main one I can't recognize who each data belongs to.

Should I store the same user id in every table during the signup? Doesn't it create unnecessary duplicates?

EDIT:
example

table:

```
| id | user | email | phone number| password | followers | following | likes | posts |
```

becomes

table 1:

```
| id | user | email | phone number| password |
```

table 2:

```
| id | followers num | following num | likes num | posts num |
```

Comment: Keep one table.  Splitting tables into smaller tables is a SQL anti-pattern and very inefficient.

Comment: What Gordon said. Just make sure there is an index on user_id. If the data ends up REALLY REALLY big and is seldom queried across users, you _might_ want to consider partitioning; but more often than not that is overkill.

Comment: If you want to do this, You have to change all query that access users to a union of both table swhere Id = 1234

Comment: @nbk I wouldn't do that, because in one table there are users' information (like email, phone number, nickname...) and in the other one users' data (like posts, followers...)

Comment: @Uueerdo so should I keep users' informations (like email or password) and users' data (like followers or posts) into the same table? I read somewhere that it is better to keep for exaple passwords in different places for security issue

Comment: Ah you want to split horizontally and not vertically, the you have to genrae a second table, with a unique key and reference this in the first table, so you can inner join, but i don't think that would take that much load from it because you must always use the inner join.

Comment: @nbk how to reference to another table? and should I store unique keys multiple times for each table?

Comment: @Fox I think it would help you with your design to learn more about relationships:  One-to-one relationships, One-to-many relationships, Many-to-many relationships

Comment: Yes of course you need to store the same key in both tables, so you can join together rows from different tables that concern the same user. If you do split your table, then there is absolutely no other way to do it. If you only duplicate the user's id then it's not duplication, it's a foreign key. As to whether you should split your table or not, I say probably not but sometimes maybe yes. However, your mentioning of followers and posts (plural) makes me think maybe you're actually going to have one-to-many relationships and not one-to-one as you think?

Comment: @downernn I read about foreign keys and now it is all clearer of course... But I can't understand whether I should manually store IDs into each table or foreign keys automatically do it

Comment: No, they don't "automatically do it". In most cases you will probably have an auto-increment column be the id of your main table, for example the one that holds the user's information. So when you add the info of a new user, he/she is automatically given an id. Then when you want to add a user's data to the second table, you will need to insert that specific user's id together with the rest of his/her data.

Comment: Oh thank you! Greetings

Comment: To clarify why a foreign key would not create the referencing field; a basic "user_followers" table could consist of two fields; a `user_id` field and a `followed_by_user_id` field, both referencing (different) entries in a `users` table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to use a `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT t1.[user], t2.[posts]
FROM Table1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 AS t2 ON t1.id= t2.id
```

EDIT: Here is a link to documentation that explains [different types of JOINS](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Comment: But the problem is: should I store IDs one time for each table that I use?

Comment: In this particular example, you have the ID stored one time in Table1 because each user is unique. That's a primary key. In Table2, assuming a one-to-many relationship, the ID (foreign key in this table) can be in zero or more rows, e.g. how many followers or posts by the specific user.

Comment: I'll surely deepen into relationships for a better understanding... But does it join the two tables using rows' order? Or has it to do with Foreign Keys as Alex said?

Comment: With relational database systems you do not want to consider row order at all. You `JOIN` on the primary key and the foreign key.

Comment: And does foreign keys get data automatically for a one-to-one relationship? (IDs are the same in both tables and never repeat)

Comment: I've updated my answer with a link to documentation that explains different types of `JOINS`. You can see how to determine which table(s) you will get data from.  It is not "automatic" because you have a foreign key.  You "ask" by including a `JOIN`.

Comment: I already know how to make a JOIN, I can't understand how to store the same ID one time for all tables (during signup)

Comment: Multiple `INSERT` statements.  This could be one reason why it was suggested that you do NOT split the table.

Comment: Ok, problem solved! So, if I have single datas referring to one single user (like the example in my question), I should keep them in a single table (suggested even if here are lots of columns) or use a one-to-one relationship (not suggested). While when I have multiple datas referring to one single user I should use a one-to-many relationship and foreign keys, merging the tables when necessary using JOIN. **Right?**

Comment: Sounds like you've got it!  Best of luck to you.

Answer (score 1):

## This looks like a "XY problem".

You want to "not have a huge table". But **why** is it that you have this requirement?

Probably it's because *some* responses in *some* scenarios are slower than you expect.

Rather than split tables every which way, which as Gordon Linoff mentioned is a SQL antipattern and liable to leave you more in the lurch than before, you should **monitor** your system and measure the performances of the various queries you use, weighing them by frequency. That is, if query #1 is done one hundred thousand times per period and takes 0.2 seconds, that's 20,000 seconds you should chalk up to query #1. Query #2 which takes fifty times longer - ten full seconds - but is only run one hundred times will only accrue one twentieth of the total time of the first.

(Since long delays are *noticeable* by the end users, some use a variation of this formula in which you multiply the instances of one query for the *square* - or higher powers - of its duration in milliseconds. This way, slower queries are brought more attention to).

Be it what may, once you know *which* queries you should optimize first, *then* you can start optimizing your schema.

The first thing to check are indexes. And maybe normalization. Those cover a good two thirds of the "low performing" cases I have met so far.

Then there's segmentation. Not in your case maybe, but you might have a table of transactions or such where you're usually only interested in the current solar or fiscal year. *Adding* a column with that information will make the table larger, but selecting only those records that at minimum match a condition on the year will make most queries run much faster. This is supported at a lower level also (see "Sharding").

Then there are careless JOINs and sub-SELECTs. Usually they start small and fast, so no one bothers to check indexes, normalization or conditions on those. After a couple of years, the inner SELECT is gathering in one million records, and the outer JOIN discards nine hundred and ninety-nine thousand of them. Translate the discarding condition inside the subselect and see the query take off.

Then you can check whether some information is really rarely accessed (for example, I have one DB where each user has a bunch of financial information, but this is only needed in maybe 0.1% of requests. So in that case yes, I have split that information in a secondary table, also gaining the possibility of supporting users with multiple bank accounts enrolled in the system. [That was not](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it) why I did it, mind you).

In all this, also take into account time and money. Doing the analysis, running the modifications and *checking them out*, plus any downtime, is going to cost something and possibly even increase maintenance costs. Maybe - just maybe - throwing less money than that into a faster disk or more RAM or more or faster CPUs might achieve the same improvements without any need to alter either the schema or your code base.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I understand your question and if you are wondering, you can use a foreign key. When you have a list of users, make sure that each user has a specific id.

Later, when you insert data about a user you can insert the users id via a session variable or a get request. (insert into different table)

Then, when you need to pull data for that specific user from that different table/s, you can just select from table where id = session[id] or get[id]

does that help?

answer: use foreign key to identify users data using gets and sessions

don't worry about duplicates if you are removing those values form the main table.

Comment: it helps a lot but I can't figure out how to do that... (I'm quite new in SQL and I don't know how to implement it, a guide would be enough)

Comment: are you just using sql? any server side language

Comment: MySQL from phpAdmin

Comment: just keep an id of the users.

Comment: and when you create another table, have that same id for the users be the id for the other table

Comment: [this one](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp)?

Comment: yeah, that's right, and Morpheus is correct. you can use a join. just join on the main tables primary key and the other tables random key. both keys being the same.

Comment: Are they automatically the same or do I have to make them equal when I store data?

Comment: you have to make them the same

Comment: No problem! Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

One table would probably have an `AUTO_INCREMENT` for the `PRIMARY KEY`; the other table would have the identical PK, but it would not be `AUTO_INCREMENT`.  `JOINing` the tables will put the tables "back together" for querying.

There is rarely a good reason to "vertically partition" a table.  One rare case is to split out the "like_count" or "view_count".  This way the main table would not be bothered by the incessant `UPDATEing` of the counters.  In some extreme cases, this may help performance.